# It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-integration

The type `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` cannot be resolved.

It is indirectly referenced from required .class files (error is in a first line of code ).

I have not imported `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException`still it is showing the error.

```
(Error) /**
 *@author Infosys
 *Create Date   Created on Nov 23, 2011 
 *Sr.No.    Modification Date       Modified By             Reason
 * 1.0      11/28/2011              Vasu Rathore            Initial code for P8344b
 */

package com.aetna.channel.catsIntake.common.util.sp;


import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;
import com.aetna.channel.catsIntake.caseId.spAdapters.ComplaintAndAppealCaseIdGenSP;
import com.aetna.channel.catsIntake.common.exceptions.CatsControllerException;
import com.aetna.channel.catsIntake.common.exceptions.CatsDatabaseException;
import com.aetna.channel.catsIntake.common.exceptions.CatsExceptionConstants;
import com.aetna.channel.catsIntake.common.exceptions.CatsIntakeSvcDAOException;
import com.aetna.channel.catsIntake.common.exceptions.CatsInvalidInputException;
import com.aetna.channel.catsIntake.common.exceptions.CatsNoDataFoundExeception;
import com.aetna.channel.catsIntake.common.util.dao.CatsLookUpDao;
```

Comment: posting the code will be much more helpful...

Comment: What is the question? Please give us the complete stacktrace. What are your dependencies? So far we only can read the exception to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` is contained in `spring-tx-<version>.jar` so you are probably missing that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in Spring project and I added the spring jdbc dependency which resolved my issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```